# Which DOMPurify isSupported should I use?

Tags: node.js, dompurify

I'm using DOMPurify with Node.js.

Code from [here](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify#running-dompurify-on-the-server)

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

const window = new JSDOM('').window;
const purify = DOMPurify(window);
const clean = purify.sanitize('<b>hello there</b>');

console.log(DOMPurify.isSupported) // -> false
console.log(purify.isSupported) // -> true
```

I'm guessing `purify.isSupported` is the value I should be checking since I'm using node like this. **Can I just ignore `DOMPurify.isSupported`?**

I'm assuming DOMPurify.isSupported doesn't matter since I'm using `purify` to sanitize. Is that correct?

Call me paranoid, just want to avoid XSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [source code](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify/blob/5f77429138aafe1bc6f8186e077d9922eb8d67fc/src/purify.js#L92), you can see that `DOMPurify.isSupported` is always false

```
if (!window || !window.document || window.document.nodeType !== 9) {
  // Not running in a browser, provide a factory function
  // so that you can pass your own Window
  DOMPurify.isSupported = false;

  return DOMPurify;
}
```